# Building a collapsible and expandable panel in asp.net

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net, css, panel

I have the following code for two panels:

```
    <asp:Panel runat="server" class="sectionLabels">
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="DetailsForm"></asp:Label>
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel ID="Details" runat="server" CssClass="panelStyle">
<table>
<tr>
<td class="columnA">
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Name"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="Name"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="columnA">
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Contact"></asp:Label>
</td>
<td>
<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="ContactDetails"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</asp:Panel>
```

I tried AJAX CollapsiblePanel method and jQuery toggle method.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Basically when the first panel is click, the second should be hidden or shown alternatively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery would make it really easy:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#contentPanel").hide();
        $("#headerPanel").click(function () {
            $(this).next("#contentPanel").slideToggle("medium");
        });
    });
```

Also, you could use classes rather than ID's which would come in very handy when there are lots of repetitive functions.

Answer (score 1):

try this, here #panel1 and #panel2 are ids of your panel tag

```
$('#panel1, #panel2').click(function(){
     if($('#panel1').is(':visible'))
     {
       $('#panel1').hide();
       $('#panel2').show();
     }
     else if($('#panel2').is(':visible'))
     {
       $('#panel2').hide();
       $('#panel1').show();
     }
   });
```

Comment: have you change panel id to panel1 and panel2, can you share a JSFiddle link? It is working at my side.

Answer (score 1):

add a div around each panel and set IDs to both

id=div1 with panel1
id=div2 with panel2

```
$("document").ready(function(){
     //hide div2 onload
     $("#div2").hide();

     $("#div1").click(function(){
         $("div2").slideDown('normal');
         $("div1").slideup('normal');
     });
     $("#div2").click(function(){
         $("div1").slideDown('normal');
         $("div2").slideup('normal');
     });
});
```